# change 'update cart' text in cart page Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to change text of the update cart button. Please I need the code in functions.php file which can change/edit 'update cart' text in the cart page in Woocommerce. 
thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy and paste the below function to your functions.php and change the text. This works. Tested

```
function change_update_cart_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_cart() && $translated == 'Update cart' ){
        $translated = 'New Text Here';
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_update_cart_text', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Find: >> cart.php

Then Find:

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 
'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); 
?></button>
```

Try changing the second 'Update cart' and tell me what happens.

Comment: ok...? If you ask me to the nearest McDonalds... and I know it's closed for renovations, I won't tell you where's that McDonalds, even if it's closer than the burger king I'm sending you to.

Comment: thanks for you answer but i didnt find it on my theme. i tried another solution. added function on my functions.php

function change_update_cart_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_cart() && $translated == 'Update cart' ){
        $translated = 'New Text Here';
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_update_cart_text', 20, 3 );

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get at this text is to copy the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php` file to your theme at `wp-content/themes/YOUR_RAD_THEME/woocommerce/cart/cart.php`

From there you can search that file for "Update cart". You should find it in two places inside a button tag.

`<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>`

Update the second one `<?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>` to whatever text you need. Bonus is that you can also edit other parts of the cart using that file.

I would avoid using `gettext` because that's a global WordPress filter. In other words, it's going to replace your string anyplace on the site, not just that button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @melvin i tried this code for Turkish. Worked :)

if you should paste your functions.php. Don't forget change here 'Sepeti Güncelle'

```
function change_update_cart_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_cart() && $translated == 'Update cart' ){
        $translated = 'Sepeti Güncelle';
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_update_cart_text', 20, 3 );

function change_update_apply_coupon( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_cart() && $translated == 'Apply coupon' ){
        $translated = 'Kuponu Uygula';
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_update_apply_coupon', 20, 3 );

function change_update_coupon_code_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_cart() && $translated == 'Coupon code' ){
        $translated = 'Kupon Kodu';
    }
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_update_coupon_code_text', 20, 3 );
```